# Apache Rewrite Rule Loop

Tags: apache, loops, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule that sends all traffic from one URL to another. For example, if somebody goes to:

https://www.mysite.co.uk/bundles/mypage.css?v=1234

I'd like the server to transparently send the request to:

https://www.mysite.co.uk/proxy/kibana.php/bundles/mypage.css?v=1234

I've added the following rewrite rule to apache config but I seem to be getting into a loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kibana.php/
RewriteRule /bundles/(.*)$ /proxy/kibana.php/bundles/$1 [P,L]
```

But the browser seems to be getting into a rewrite loop. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I posted a little too quickly. I swapped out [P,L] with [NC,L,QSA] and all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition should be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/proxy/kibana.php/
```

Comment: Thanks for the really quick answer - see my answer below